# display array list as high scores in android studio

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am really new to android and have project that involves keeping up with high scores in a quiz.  How do I display the Array List on the fragment after the game is complete?

```
  public void saveHighScores(int score) {
       ArrayList<String> topFiveHighScoresList;

       // store the saved scores in an ArrayList
       topFiveHighScoresList = new ArrayList<String>(topFiveHighScoresPreference.getAll().keySet());

       // add the latest score to the list
       topFiveHighScoresList.add(Integer.toString(score));

       // sort the scores
       Collections.sort(topFiveHighScoresList, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
            // remove the last score from the list if the list exceeds 5 items.
       if (topFiveHighScoresList.size() > 5)
           topFiveHighScoresList.remove(5);

       SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditor;
       preferencesEditor = topFiveHighScoresPreference.edit();

       preferencesEditor.clear();
       preferencesEditor.apply();

   }
```

Comment: What do you mean by `after the game is complete`?

Comment: Did you found useful the answer or you need something else

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom Dialog (extends Dialog).

In the next code you will show a Dialog with the scores.

First the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#dc000000">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_close_text"
        android:id="@+id/button_close"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/linear_layout">
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The XML above is going to show a button in top, a list of elements (key - value) in the LinearLayout with id: linear_layout.

Second the Custom Dialog:

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomDialog extends Dialog {

    private LinearLayout layout;
    private Context mContext;

    public CustomDialog(Context context) {

        super(context, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
        setContentView(R.layout.dialog_content);
        setCancelable(false);
        mContext = context;

        Button buttonClose = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_close);
        buttonClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dismiss();
            }
        });

        layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);
    }

    public void addKeyValuePair(String key, String value) {

        TextView textView_key = (TextView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row_key, layout, false);
        TextView textView_value = (TextView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row_value, layout, false);

        textView_key.setText(key);
        textView_value.setText(value);

        layout.addView(textView_key);
        layout.addView(textView_value);
    }
}
```

With the method: addKeyValuePair(String key, String value) you are going to add the scores to the dialog before show it.

You still need the XML for your key-value for each row:

row_key.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="dummy_text"
    android:id="@+id/row_textView_key"
    android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20sp">
</TextView>
```

row_value.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="dummy_value"
    android:id="@+id/row_textView_value"
    android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="30sp">
</TextView>
```

Under your FragmentActivity, when you want to show the scores:

```
CustomDialog cd = new CustomDialog(this);
cd.addKeyValuePair("key","value");
```

That is all.